# PHP uploading images in the correct dimensions

Tags: php

I know this question is very common but the main point in my question is that i want to know how facebook or some other websites upload their pictures in the correct size. for example. if we upload a picture of the dimension : width : 1000px , height : 20px. then facebook updates the status updates with that pic but makes the image size small in the correct ratio. its jus scales down the picture but we can know that the image is very widthy (my own word for very high width :P) where as long heighty pictures are also posted in the correct proportion.

[image: PIC NUMBER 1]

[image: PIC NUMBER 2]

I have included the image examples above. how does facebook calculate the size n ratio of the pics and echo out the pic by keeping the right dimensions but scaling it down at the same time.

Comment: What actually happens is the the image is recreated on the server and scaled by a multiplier (width * .5). So, really, you aren't seeing the original image at all. You are seeing a new image the server created.

Comment: @Scott - i dint get u :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is fairly verbose, but might give you an idea on how to calculate image dimensions.

Parameters are your source width and your target maximum resize width and heights

```
function image_resize_dimensions($source_width,$source_height,$thumb_width,$thumb_height)
{
  $source_ratio = $source_width / $source_height;
  $thumb_ratio = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

  // Ratio is Taller
  if ($thumb_ratio > $source_ratio)
  {
    $result_height = $thumb_height;
    $result_width = $thumb_height * $source_ratio;
  }

  // Ratio is Wider
  elseif ($thumb_ratio < $source_ratio)
  {
    $result_width = $thumb_width;
    $result_height = $thumb_width / $source_ratio;
  }

  // Ratio the Same
  elseif($thumb_ratio == $source_ratio)
  {
    $result_height = $thumb_height;
    $result_width = $thumb_width;
  }

  return array('x'=>$result_width,'y'=>$result_height);

}
```

Comment: when calling image_resize_jpg(), the 1st $image parameter is the path to your source, 2nd $filename is the destination path, 3rd/4th $thumb_width/height are the maximum of the re sized images, 5th $maximize by default is false but when set to true will crop parts of the image to force the dimensions, 6th $quality is image quality from 0 to 100, and 7th $image_object if you want to pass in an existing object.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few factors.

1. the main factor is the width of the content the image is displayed in
2. the original width of the image
3. whether you want to fill the whole content with the image or not (Facebook doesn't)

Let's say you have an image which has a width of 1000px. Your content is 400px. You want to fill the content a half with your image, so you have an end width of 200px for your image. The height is just ca percental calculation (rule of three).

In the end, you will have the correct ratio and it fits well in your content.

Of course you could also check whether the image is 16:9 or 4:3 to determine the max width for images like your first example.

Comment: i understood the points but i dint understand the last part of ratios i.e. the part in which u wrote 16:9 and 4:3. and yea i have done the percental calculation for the height