# PHP image resize depending on height

Tags: php, image, math, image-resizing, image-size

Hey all i am trying to figure out how to resize an image that has a higher height than width. The normal width and height of the area where the image needs to be displayed is:

```
width  = 1000px
height = 700px
```

What type of math would i need in order to resize that to the proper width/height above without screwing it?

The test image size is:

```
 width  = 1451
 height = 2200
```

I was thinking of doing this:

```
(700/org.height)
```

But that does not come up with the correct number of **462**.

In photoshop, changing the height to **700** yields a width value of **462**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863653/algorithm-to-resize-image-and-maintain-aspect-ratio-to-fit-iphone - it doesn't matter which language you apply this to. the math is the same. You know, though, imagemagick can do this very easily for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674856/php-uploading-images-in-the-correct-dimensions  My answer in this question should assist you with producing the dimension within the confines of a maximum size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to scale your image so that it fits as large as possible within a 1000x700 square without stretching it?  You could do something like this:

```
$availH = 700;
$availW = 1000;
$imageH = 2200;
$imageW = 1451;

// you know you want to limit the height to 700
$newH = $availH;

// figure out what the ratio was that you adjusted (will equal aprox 0.3181)
$ratio = $availH / $imageH;

// now that you have the $ratio you can apply that to the width (will equal 462)
$newW = round(imageW * $ratio);
```

Now you have $newW and $newH which are the new sizes for your image properly scaled.  You could of course condense this down but I've written it out so each step is more clear.

Comment: That was it. Thanks, Jason!

Answer (score 0):

Formula to keep aspect ratio when resizing is

```
original height / original width x new width = new height
```

Source: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/

But you want to switch it around to the following I think:

```
original width / original height x new height = new width
```

Comment: So for the height it would be 700 and then whatever that **original width / original height x new height** is for the width?

Comment: ..That wont produce the **462** that photoshop does?